Search HTML for words and mark by wrapping with a span
I have HTML content (content edited via a CMS, not an entire website page) and when a search is performed, I need to highlight the searched for words by wrapping the words with a span.
So, consider the HTML content, when the search term is "commissioner":
> <p>
> In this section, we set out how the Commissioner regulates those
> who provide advice. For details, see 
> <a href="/the-commissioner/" title="The Commissioner">The Commissioner</a>
> </p>

I need to add a span around the work "Commissioner" in the text part of the link but NOT the URL or Title part of the link. Of course, also, I would need to add a span around "Commissioner" in the content too.
I tried using Regex but I couldn't see how to not change the link Url or Title.
I have looked at HtmlAgilityPack but it looks like you can't change the value of "InnerText" (of a node) so I don't understand how I can update the HTML and add the required spans.
Would I need to build a new HTML document instead of amending the one I'm reading through?

I think it would be better to do that on the client side. Do you have to do it on the server side?

@FernandoDelCantão no, I don’t suppose it has to be server side  - but I don’t know how to do it client side either!

Could probably do something like this

Forget regex for this. That out of the way: What use case are you trying to implement and where is this running (supposed to run)? If you do that on the server, you need to serve the changes to the client (how is another question) - if on the client, you'll probably mutate the DOM from JS. But most importantly why is this done by span and not a complete Client (as in "the Browser") thing?

@Fildor it is a CMS managed website (.Net Core). Personally, I'd rather do it on the server side as I'm not a JS programmer.

This program tries to solve the problem by taking the searched text that is not surrounded by characters used in html tags or url syntax.
Solution
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace StackOverflowAnswers
{
    public class ProgramStack78911999
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Commissioner";
            Console.WriteLine("Input:  " + input);
            SearchTextInHTML(input);
        }

        static void SearchTextInHTML(string search_text)
        {
            string content = "" +
                "<p>In this section, we set out how the Commissioner regulates those" +
                "who provide advice. For details, see " +
                "<a href=\"/the-commissioner/\" title=\"The Commissioner\">The Commissioner</a>" +
                "</p>";
            Console.WriteLine("Content");
            Console.WriteLine(content);
            Console.WriteLine("Matches");
            string pattern_group = @"([^\-""\/<>]{1})\b(" + search_text + @")\b([^\-""\/<>]{1})";
            string replace_group = "$1<span>$2</span>$3";
            string new_content = content;
            foreach (Match mtc in Regex.Matches(content, pattern_group))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mtc);
                new_content = Regex.Replace(new_content, pattern_group, replace_group);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("New Content");
            Console.WriteLine(new_content);
        }
    }
}

Output
<p>In this section, we set out how the <span>Commissioner</span> regulates thosewho provide advice. For details, see <a href="/the-commissioner/" title="The Commissioner">The Commissioner</a></p>


I solved this by using the Javascript library mark.js to do the highlighting on the clients browser.
On the HTML pages, the content goes inside an article tag.
<article class="article"> ... </article>

I used this Javascript. The search words are passed as a Querystring property ("q"). I also pass a property called "exact".
import Mark from 'mark.js'

// Create an instance of mark.js and pass an argument containing
// the DOM object of the context (where to search for matches)
var markInstance = new Mark(document.querySelector(".article"));

function performMark() {

    // Read the keywords
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    var keyword = params.get("q")
    var separateWords = true;
    if (params.get("ExactMatch").toLowerCase() == 'true') {
        separateWords = false;
    }

    // Determine selected options
    var options = {
        "separateWordSearch": separateWords,
        "accuracy": {
            "value": "exactly",
            "limiters": [",", "."]
        }
    };
    // Remove previous marked elements and mark
    // the new keyword inside the context
    markInstance.unmark({
        done: function () {
            markInstance.mark(keyword, options);
        }
    });
};

performMark();

So, if a page has a querystring like "?q=student+advice&exact=true", the exact phrase of "student advice" will be highlighted by surrounding it with the "mark" tag.

Try to share your solution with the community, just as the rest share their time with your problem. At the moment only you know the solution. The other answers will be more relevant to whoever finds this post in the future.

@camilo_chart I have updated my answer to include more information about how I used the mark.js JavaScript library
